# Adamantine vs adamantine

Tags: dnd-3.5e

So other discussions got me thinking in circles.

Special materials of 3.5 DND say adamantine weapons bypass hardness less than 20. Adamantine has a hardness 20.

How would sundering work between the 2? Normally or will the sword bypass

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since adamantine has hardness 20, and 20 is not *less* than 20, another adamantine sword will not be able to bypass its hardness. A sundering attempt will work as normal.

Comment: And what would happen if it had 21? Or does this never be given?

Comment: It still bypass hardness less than 20 not it's own hardness-1